# viewing classes by label in Topbraid Composer

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, topbraid-composer

I'm drawing out the relationships between some individuals in Topbraid Composer Maestro Edition.  My core ontology is OBIB from the OBO Foundry, so a term like ***biobank*** has an IRI like `<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OMIABIS_0000000>`, or `obo:OMIABIS_0000000`.  I'd like to see them labeled, in the graph and in the class bowser, with their rdfs:labels, not their IDs.

Is this possible?  I can't find it in ***Windows -> Preferences -> Topbraid Composer***

Comment: Perhaps the rightmost icon on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a26lv.png) (unfortunately, I can't test now).

Comment: There must be an option *"Toggle between qnames and human-readable rdfs:labels"* - see page 10 of http://www.topquadrant.com/docs/marcom/TBC-Getting-Started-Guide.pdf  This should be exactly the icon that Stanislav mentioned, the human top right somewhere next to the house icon.

Comment: Thanks, guys.  The human icon does what I wanted and is intuitive after the fact!